# how to work with ui-view in ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic to build a hybrid app and I can't get the ui-view to dynamically show content

this is the index

```
<body ng-app="starter">
 <ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</ion-pane>
</body>
```

for my understanding the ion-nav-view work just like the ui-view from angular ui-routing.

this is my app.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$stateProvider

.state('login',{
    url: '/',
    template: '<h1>hello</h1>'
})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

})
```

I want the word hello to show when going to the root of the app but is not working. it's not showing anything and is not giving any console error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the "hello" is there, but it's getting obscured by the `<ion-header-bar>`. Try adding "has-header" as a class to the `<ion-nav-view>` element. That class forces the content to begin 44px lower than usual, to account for the header bar.

Here is a working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPZVvq). All I did was add that class.